# Node - How to catch split() error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, unhandled

I have a question about NodeJs. Since 6.6 it say when unhandled promise can't be fetched.

To avoid that, I red I need to catch the error, but... If I got that, how should I proceed?

```
args[1] = args[1].split('!')[1].split('>')[0]
```

I tried to add .catch(err => console.log(err)) but nothing seems to change.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The code you posted is not async, neither returns a promise.

Comment: You want to update your code snippet

Comment: Does the code contain nested `Promise`s?

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of catching, you can avoid an error by substituting a string when the first split produces no second index.

```
args[1] = (args[1].split('!')[1] || "").split('>')[0];
```

---

This assumes that `args[1]` is definitely present. If that's not certain, you can do a similar substitution.

```
args[1] = ((args[1] || "").split('!')[1] || "").split('>')[0];
```

---

And finally, you can provide a default value in case any part of that failed to produce something useful.

```
args[1] = ((args[1] || "").split('!')[1] || "").split('>')[0] || "DEFAULT";
```

Answer (score 0):

.catch(err => console.log(err)) is used to catch errors from promises. Use the standard form instead:

```
try{
    args[1] = args[1].split('!')[1].split('>')[0]
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less this is not promising. it's just a simple javascript statement which can be captured directly as below:
Try using try catch on the whole

```
try{
   args[1] = args[1].split('!')[1].split('>')[0]
}catch(e){
console.log(e); 
// Most possible error would be TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:23
}
```